# C++ do I need to initialise an stl field in a default constructor?

Tags: c++, dictionary, constructor, stl, default

So, say I have a class like this (C++, not C++11):

```
Class A{
    A();
    std::map<int,int> my_map;
}
```

If I want to write my constructor, should I do something like this?

```
A::A(){my_map();}
```

Or should I just leave the constructor empty if I want an empty map?

Comment: You don't need to do anything because `std::map` has its own default constructor that will be called. Unless you want to construct your `std::map` with non-default parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have mistaken the constructor body for the [member-initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). The member-initializer list is what's used to actually construct the data members and base classes by calling their constructors. It starts with a colon followed by a comma separated list of constructor calls. For your example, to call the default-constructor on `my_map`, you'd use this syntax:

```
A::A() : my_map() { }
```

The initializer list constructs `my_map` using its default-constructor, and then the constructor body executes. This is useful if you have data members that you'd want to initialize differently, but if all your constructor does is explicitly call the default-constructor of all your data members, then it really isn't all that different from the *compiler-generated* default constructor.

**TL;DR**: In this case, you don't need to write your own constructor as the compiler will provide one for you.